# Book mainly discuss quotient topology

Tags: general-topology, book-recommendation, quotient-spaces

I am studying general topology, but I can't grasp the 'feeling' of quotient topology.

I know the 'gluing' metaphor, but I always have no idea when I am asked to determine whether two quotient space(of different space) homeomorphic, finding the homeomorphism etc. Also, I am not so  what else the concept 'quotinet topology ' can do, so, is there any books discuss mainly quotient topology? Thank you.

Comment: First make sure you have a good basic topology textbook which covers all aspects of the quotient topology, such as the book by Munkres. Then get a good book that explains in detail how surfaces are constructed as quotients by gluing sides of polygons, such as Stillwell's "Classical topology and combinatorial group theory". Otherwise, your question is rather vague, so it's hard to know what might help you.

Comment: I am also interested in a book that have a lot of material about quotient topology. I hope this question dont get closed.